# Missing boost ICU regex symbol at link time on MacOS with brew

Tags: c++, macos, boost, homebrew, icu

I've changed my regex's to use the ICU library and having link problems on OSX.  In particular I have one undefined symbol:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::basic_regex<int, boost::icu_regex_traits>::do_assign(int const*, int const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
```

I have the appropriate link libraries: `-lboost_regex -licui18n -licuuc -licudata`.

I used brew to remove and reinstall both `icu4c` and `boost`. I checked the libraries are in the right place. I also checked that there isn't a second boost_regex_icu library (did not find one).

I use `scons` as a build system and it's found all the libraries. The headers are also correct as the code compiles correct, but fails at the linking stage. It's also curiously only this one symbol that is missing, not the rest of the boost regex/icu library.

What might I be doing wrong?

---

My full link line: `g++ -o build/libleaf_lang.dylib -rpath @executable_path -install_name @rpath/libleaf_lang.dylib -dynamiclib build/lang/assign_statement.os build/lang/cerr.os build/lang/class_typer.os build/lang/context.os build/lang/conversion_applicator.os build/lang/declaration.os build/lang/do_statement.os build/lang/dump.os build/lang/error_statement.os build/lang/expression.os build/lang/expression_statement.os build/lang/expression_visitor.os build/lang/fail_statement.os build/lang/for_statement.os build/lang/import_statement.os build/lang/init_statement.os build/lang/intr_type.os build/lang/loop_flow_statement.os build/lang/module.os build/lang/module_loader.os build/lang/noop_statement.os build/lang/return_statement.os build/lang/scope.os build/lang/scope_ref.os build/lang/serial.os build/lang/serial_expression.os build/lang/serial_type.os build/lang/statement_block.os build/lang/statement.os build/lang/statement_importer.os build/lang/statement_visitor.os build/lang/type_converter.os build/lang/type_identifier.os build/lang/type_manager.os build/lang/typer.os build/lang/type_ref.os build/lang/type_spec.os build/lang/typedef_statement.os build/lang/var_statement.os build/lang/expression_typer/builtin.os build/lang/expression_typer/common.os build/lang/expression_typer/fields.os build/lang/expression_typer/funccall.os build/lang/expression_typer/funcdefn.os build/lang/expression_typer/funccall_ctor.os build/lang/expression_typer/funccall_type.os build/parser/intr_type_parser.os build/parser/node_parser.os build/parser/node_converter.os build/parser/dump.os build/parser/source.os build/platform/platform.os build/platform/gnu_linux_x86_64.os -Lbuild/build/lib -Lsrc/build/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib -Lbuild -Lsrc -L/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2/lib -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lgmp -lgmpxx -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lyaml-cpp -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lleaf_util`

Brew packages:

- boost: stable 1.67.0 (bottled), HEAD
- icu4c: stable 61.1 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]

Answer (score 2):

Brew's boost packages are not created with icu4c support by default. They must be installed as:

```
brew install boost --with-icu4c
```

Or if already installed:

```
brew reinstall boost --with-icu4c
```

Be patient while boost compiles, as this doesn't appear to use a standard binary.

*There are some notes on mailing lists/bug reports that icu4c should be detected during boost's install, but it appears that it is no. The order I installed icu4c/boost made no difference. Only the above flag seemed to help.*